# Bootstrap like UI in YUI

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yui, zurb-foundation

I am using YUI framework for frontEnd.

My main motive is to make my site look good. So when I was reading I came across BootStrap, foundation but not sure whether we can use it with YUI or not.

Any Suggestion on how should we proceed.

Note: YUI as frontEnd framework.

Thanks
Amit Aggarwal

Comment: Have you asked Google?

Comment: @JonasG.Drange : Obviously. For everyone Google is first point of contact but I got confused so I post this question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One alternative for Twitter Bootstrap for using YUI is [pureCSS](http://purecss.io/). Pure CSS was developed by Yahoo and is not dependent on any javascript library. Please note that Twitter Bootstrap is jQuery dependent.

PUre CSS Description from their website:

```
A set of small, responsive CSS modules that you can use in every web project.
```

Also, because purecss is not dependent on any js library, you can use it with everything. Wether is it jQuery or Angular or Backbone e.t.c
But of course, if you're not satisfied with this solution you can find a gazillion of other grid-based css libraries, but the idea is the same.

Have fun!